# How do I return times that don't show up in a column through pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an Excel spreadsheet of several years of orders I'm looking at. One column is 'Order Date Time'. I want to return a table with the most common HH:MM (not :SS) that *don't* appear, within certain parameters (e.g. > 10:00, after opening hours and < 23:00 before closing).

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing this and have had great success getting assistance here in the past. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your DataFrame contains something like below:

```
      Order Date Time  Amount
0 2020-01-02 10:00:00      62
1 2020-01-02 10:46:43      18
2 2020-01-02 11:38:15      56
3 2020-01-02 11:55:37      34
4 2020-01-02 12:46:22      41
5 2020-01-02 13:00:34      61
6 2020-01-02 13:58:08      46
7 2020-01-02 14:32:45      38
8 2020-01-02 14:44:31      12
9 2020-01-02 15:08:44      39
...
```

that is:

- *Order Date Time* - date / time of the event, of *datetime* type
  (if you read it as a *string*, you have converted it calling
  *pd.to_datetime*),
- *Amount* (and possibly other columns) - data concerning each order.

You can  get the result as follows:

1. Generate a temporary DataFrame with rows meeting your condition:

   ```
   df2 = df['Order Date Time'].dt.hour.between(10, 22)
   ```
2. Set the number of most common hours/minutes:

   ```
   n = 10
   ```
3. Compute the actual result:

   ```
   df2.groupby(df['Order Date Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')).size()\
       .sort_values(ascending=False).head(n)
   ```

Details:

- `df2.groupby(...)` - group orders by hour / minute (ignoring seconds and
  the date part),
- `size()` - compute the size of each group,
- `sort_values(...)` - sort (descending order),
- `head(n)` - get top *n* values.

For my working data I got:

```
Order Date Time
10:00     20
22:51     17
19:04     15
13:24     15
13:50     14
13:10     14
12:58     14
15:29     14
19:17     13
18:03     13
```

Comment: This is helpful and gets me part of the way there. How might I go about finding the times that aren't present? Thank you so much!

Comment: Generate a *Series* containing all "possible" *hh:mm* strings (within your time limit). Then drop all strings present in the result of my code and you will have "not present" hours/minutes.